# Using the Output of Sysinternals Process Monitor in another programm/script in real time

Tags: python, windows, process, process-monitor

I'm working on a script that should check on certain system events (like opening of a file, or changing of a registry key) and start further actions depending on that. But I haven't found a clean way to get the information into my script.

I'm looking for a way to get the output of Sysinternals Process Monitor into another program. This should happen without user interaction in close to real time; so saving into a CSV/XML and than using this doesn't work.
I've checked on using the backing file, but this is in the Process Monitor PML format, which i haven't found to be documented anywhere.

Does anybody know a way how I can get the output of Process Monitor into my script?
Or an other (not too messy) way to get a real time list of opened files, registry keys etc into a python program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse stdout or a file, and your ok with a 32 bit only solution, try [Dr Strace](http://drmemory.org/docs/page_drstrace.html) or [ntstrace](http://www.zoneos.com/ntstrace.htm).

YOu could also look into [ospy](https://code.google.com/p/ospy/) or another ProcMon alternative. ospy is open source, so at the very least you could look at the source code for capturing events.

[Here is a list of alternates](http://alternativeto.net/software/process-monitor/?platform=windows) to ProcMon.